# Помогите разобраться, нужно ли ли ставить запятые перед именами

Tags: пунктуация

От всей души поздравляем нашего уважаемого директора Иванову Ирину Викторовну, нашу дорогую Галину Васильевну, нашу любимую учительницу Иванову Ирину Михайловну и всех ребят, и их родителей с наступающим 2020 годом!

Answer (score 1):

Перед именами не нужно запятых! С очень большой натяжкой, если как бы передаётся на письме пауза в речи перед произнесением имени, можно тире. (Можно, но не нужно.)

Тут другая проблемная запятая:

> и всех ребят, и их родителей с...

Это не просто повторение союза *и*; поздравляется группа товарищей **и** детки с папами-мамами.

Корректно:

*От всей души поздравляем нашего уважаемого директора Иванову Ирину Викторовну, нашу дорогую Галину Васильевну, нашу любимую учительницу Иванову Ирину Михайловну и всех ребят и их родителей с наступающим 2020 годом!*

Answer (score 0):

Запятые перед именами ставим, также для ясности можно разделить однородные члены на две группы:

*От всей души поздравляем нашего уважаемого директора Иванову Ирину Викторовну, нашу дорогую Галину Васильевну, нашу любимую учительницу Иванову Ирину Михайловну, **а также всех ребят и их родителей** с наступающим 2020 годом!*